# Can't get an old WPF Project to work on a new system

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I installed a new SSD with a new windows, transferred old WPF projects to it, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize it as WPF, intellisense doesn't work, I can't add UserControls. Is there any way to fix that? Everything works fine when I try to start a new project. Visual Studio 2019 16.6.5

Comment: Did you add the ."NET desktop development" workload from the Visual Studio installer? VS 2019 is normally good at prompting you when you're missing a workload. Go to Tools -> Get Tools and Features, then "Workloads" tab and select ".NET desktop development", then "Modify"

Comment: I have that installed, as I said everything works fine when I try to start a new one.

Comment: How did you try to open them? Opening the .sln file or starting VS and opening them via Open >  Project/Solution? Try opening ONLY the project if you did not already.

Comment: I tried opening it  both ways it doesn't work.

Comment: When having issues with visual studio I sometimes can solve them by deleting the .vs folders of the projects and then starting the project again. Not sure if it helps something but you should give it a try. As well restart your computer etc. All that "default" problem solving stuff. Check your installed .NET Framework version of vs and the one of your wpf project.

Comment: Deleting the vs folder helped. I thought it wasn't copied since it was hidden. I guess not working with vs for a long  time has its price. Thanks.